# Problem when move from first to last tab on TabBarView Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing a problem with my flutter app when i need to jump from the first to the third Tab. i'll explain better below:

I'm building a screen using flutter when i've a TabBar with 3 Tabs and below a TabBarView to populate this tabs.

something like that:

```
Widget _buildReportAppbar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
      elevation: 5,
      leading: ...
      title: ...
      actions: ...
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(58.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: TabBar(
            labelColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            isScrollable: true,
            indicatorWeight: 0,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: _tabs,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildReportBody() {
    return TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: _provideTabScreenList(),
    );
  }
```

My tab controller is working like a charm and inside each TabBarView I've an statefulWidget that build my report screens. Each StatefulWidget has an api call that bring me the report information and with the SetState(){} method i put the informations on the screen.

```
List<Widget> _provideTabScreenList() {
_tabScreenList.clear();
_tabScreenList.add(PeriodResumeReport(filterData: currentFilter));
_tabScreenList.add(SaleStatisticReport(filterData: currentFilter));
_tabScreenList.add(SalePerDayReport(filterData: currentFilter));
return _tabScreenList;
}


class PeriodResumeReport extends StatefulWidget {
  final _periodResumeReportState = _PeriodResumeReportState();
  final SelectedFilter filterData;

  PeriodResumeReport({Key key, @required this.filterData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PeriodResumeReportState createState() => _periodResumeReportState;

  //My tabController has a listener that detect the position change and notify the child.
  void isVisible() {
    _periodResumeReportState.isVisible();
  }
}

//I'm using the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to keep the state when i move between the 
childs of the TabBarView
class _PeriodResumeReportState extends State<PeriodResumeReport>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PeriodResumeReport> {
  var _loadingData = false;
  var _apiErrorMessage = "";
  var _hasResponseFromApi = false;

  var _response = ...api response;

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  //Load first data when the screen visible for the first time.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _reloadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        _loadingData ? LinearProgressIndicator() : Container(),
        _apiErrorMessage.isNotEmpty
            ? Padding(...)
            : Container(),
        _hasResponseFromApi ? _buildTotalOfSalesContainer() : Container(),
        _hasResponseFromApi ? _buildComparativeChart() : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTotalOfSalesContainer() {
    return ...;
  }

  Widget _buildComparativeChart() {
    return ...;
  }

  //reload data if the user return to the screen
  void isVisible() {
    _reloadData();
  }

  Future<void> _reloadData() async {
    //show ProgressBar and clear apiError
    setState(() {
      _loadingData = true;
      _apiErrorMessage = "";
    });

    try {
      var response = .... api call ....

      ....
      .... handle api response
      .... 

      setState(() {
        _response = response;
        _loadingData = false;
        _hasResponseFromApi = true;
      });
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

And with this code everything is working fine. But with one problem, if i swipe to the first tab to second and after to third tab, is all ok. The problem happen if I'm in the first tab and click to move to third tab instead to pass to the second before. Doing this, the second tab crash with this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _SaleStatisticReportState#8c846(lifecycle 
state: defunct)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer 
appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its. 
build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation 
callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the 
dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object 
before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object 
is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To 
avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().)
```

in this line:

```
@override
void setState(fn) {
    if(mounted){
      super.setState(fn);
    }
}
```

I don't know what's the problem, maybe the action of swipe from first tab directly to third tab run the isVisible method and start api call on the second tab but, as I'm on the third tab, the setState(){} on the second crash. How I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in _reloadData method because this method you are calling in initstate, so this method call setState even screen is not mounted. To solve this try following solution method.

In following solution i am making sure that screen is mounted and if it is then only call setState.

```
Future<void> _reloadData() async {
    //show ProgressBar and clear apiError
    if(mounted){
    setState(() {
      _loadingData = true;
      _apiErrorMessage = "";
    });
    }

    try {
      var response = .... api call ....

      ....
      .... handle api response
      .... 
      if(mounted)
      setState(() {
        _response = response;
        _loadingData = false;
        _hasResponseFromApi = true;
      });
      }
  }
```

Update:

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  int clockHours = 10;
  int clockMinutes = 10;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Tabbed AppBar'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "1"),
              Tab(text: "2"),
              Tab(text: "3"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Home1(),
            Home2(),
            Home3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home1State createState() => _Home1State();
}

class _Home1State extends State<Home1> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callme();
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Home2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home2State createState() => _Home2State();
}

class _Home2State extends State<Home2>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Home2> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    callme();
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    // if (mounted) {
    setState(() {});
    //}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class Home3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home3State createState() => _Home3State();
}

class _Home3State extends State<Home3>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Home3> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callme();
  }

  callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Update:

How to call child method from parent widget.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  GlobalKey<Home1State> _keyChild1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _keyChild1 = GlobalKey();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("press"),
            onPressed: () {
              _keyChild1.currentState.callme();
            },
          ),
          Home1(
            key: _keyChild1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Home1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Home1State createState() => Home1State();
}

class Home1State extends State<Home1> {
  callme() {
    print("method call from parent");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Home1"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, I already override the setState method to aways check if is mounted but no solution until now.

Comment: the error you added in question is thrown by _SaleStatisticReportState class, so did you also make sure their as you did in _PeriodResumeReportState class?

Comment: Yes, all the 3 report class are almost ctrl c + v, the only difference is the api and the body of the screen :/

Comment: i think you forgot to overwrite  super in that class because i trie in my demo and it works fine if i overwrite  super method.

Comment: i added my demo code, is it working fine for you or not. if not can you tell me to how to reproduce error, so that i can try. when i tried it works fine for me.

Comment: I checked here and it's here

`class _SaleStatisticReportState extends State<SaleStatisticReport>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SaleStatisticReport> {
  var _loadingData = true;
  var _apiErrorMessage = "";
  var _hasResponseFromApi = false;
  SelectedFilter _filterData;

  var _response = List<ReportStoreInformation>();

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }`

Comment: I tried to run flutter clean but same problem, try to click on tab3 directly from tab1, when the TabBarView move to Home3, the Home2 is created and the error happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213186/discussion-between-viren-v-varasadiya-and-felipersn).